# All pages give 404 using nginx

Tags: deployment

I am building a drupal site with drupal 9, and i want to publish it using azure devops.

Only the problem is that every page, except the frontpage, gives a 404 error. I've looked around the internet, and most people say they miss the .htaccess file, it is however included.

I can't edit files directly, and have to change it locally and then commit to change them, but it does somehow work locally.

The drupal files (including the htaccess file) are in a folder 'src'.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Edit: The server is nginx

Comment: Is it an Apache server?

Comment: It is on nginx. On apache it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx can’t process htaccess files without a specific extension installed.

You either need to install that extension or manually configure nginx to work with Drupal.

There’s an example config here if you go down the manual route: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

Comment: For the record, you mean 'php-fpm' as the extension?

Comment: No, there’s actually an extension for nginx which will make it understand htaccess - https://github.com/e404/htaccess-for-nginx. PHP-FPM is an extension that comes with PHP (which exposes a socket or TCP endpoint or socket for other processes like nginx to execute PHP commands). FPM won’t help with the rewrite rules, for that you need to configure nginx

Comment: Ah alright, thank you very much. i will try it :)